# How to get local IP address of Windows system?

Tags: windows, winapi, ip-address

Is there any code or method to get the IP addresses of the local system?

Comment: This doesn't look like c++ code, more like c#.

Comment: "Hey guys I found these random snippets of code in languages that all have "C" in their name. Please help make it work."

Comment: @dlpsankhla If you had done a bit of research on these code snippets you had before, there should be easily found their c++-cli pendants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To enumerate local IP addresses, use the Win32 API [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx) (supports IPv4 only) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) (supports IPv4 and IPv6) function.  C/C++ examples are included in their documentation.

Comment: Working example:

```
ULONG outBufLen = 15000;
PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES adapters = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *) malloc(outBufLen);
GetFAdapterAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, NULL, NULL, adapters, &outBufLen);
free(adapters);
```

both <WinSock2.h> and <iphlpapi.h> needs to be included

Answer (score 0):

If you are in C#, you could use .NET:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

public static string GetLocalIP() {
  var hosts = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
  foreach (var ipEntry in host.AddressList)
  {
    if (ipEntry.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
      return ip.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

You can later add a `throw new Exception` at the end, it will show up if you have no IPv4 adapters installed.