# Where is the ip address in IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Per this question:

[How to get local IP address of Windows system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902643/how-to-get-local-ip-address-of-windows-system)

@Remy Lebeau answered that `GetAdaptersAddresses()` was a way to get the IP address of the local machine in Windows using C++.

I compiled the example and the example does not print out the local IP address of the machine. I took a look at the struct that the function returns (`IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH`) and I was surprised to find that I did not see any references to where the actual IP address is.

My question is, where is the IP address located in the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH` struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I compiled the example and the example does not print out the local IP address of the machine.

`GetAdaptersAddresses()` has always worked fine for me.

> where is the IP address located in the IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH struct?

There are potentially *many* IP addresses in the struct, depending on what *kind* of IP address you are interested in - Unicast, Anycast, Multicast, or DnsServer.  For local assigned IPs, you would typically use the Unicast addresses only:

- The `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH::FirstUnicastAddress` field points to a linked list of [`IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-_ip_adapter_unicast_address_lh) structs, one entry for each IP address.  Use the `IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH::Next` field to loop through the list (the MSDN example shows such a loop, but it only counts the number of elements in the list, it does not print out the content of the list).
- The `IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH::Address` field contains the actual IP address, in [`SOCKET_ADDRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-_socket_address) format.
- the `SOCKET_ADDRESS::lpSockaddr` field is a [`SOCKADDR*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-sockaddr) pointer. You can pass it as-is to socket APIs like `bind()`.
- If you want to do something with the IP address (like display it), you have to type-cast the `SOCKET_ADDRESS::lpSockAddr` pointer to either [`sockaddr_in*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-sockaddr_in) or [`sockaddr_in6*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2ipdef/ns-ws2ipdef-sockaddr_in6), depending on whether the IP address is IPv4 or IPv6, respectively (use the `SOCKADDR::sa_family` field to determine the correct type - `AF_INET` for `sockaddr_in`, `AF_INET6` for `sockaddr_in6`).  Then you can access the `sockaddr_in::sin_addr` or `sockaddr_in6::sin6_addr` field as needed, which contain the actual bytes of the IP address.

For example:

```
PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = ...; // allocate buffer as needed...
ULONG ulSize = ...; // size of allocated buffer...

if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, GAA_FLAG_SKIP_ANYCAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_FRIENDLY_NAME, NULL, pAddresses, &ulSize) == 0)
{
    for (PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH *pAddress = pAddresses->FirstUnicastAddress;
        pAddress != NULL;
        pAddress = pAddress->Next)
    {
        SOCKADDR *pSockAddr = pAddress->Address.lpSockaddr;
        switch (pSockAddr->sa_family)
        {
            case AF_INET: {
                sockaddr_in *pInAddr = (sockaddr_in*) pSockAddr;
                // use pInAddr->sin_addr as needed...
                break;
            }

            case AF_INET6: {
                sockaddr_in6 *pIn6Addr = (sockaddr_in6*) pSockAddr;
                // use pIn6Addr->sin6_addr as needed...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// free pAddresses as needed ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! This worked perfectly

Comment: I want to get both IPv4 and IPv6, do I need to call GetAdapterAddresses two time or just specify AF_UNSPEC

Comment: @Zeltrax just specify `AF_UNSPEC`, as I did in my example above