# How do I get the IPv4 address of my server application?

Tags: c++, winsock2

Even after sifting through many related posts I can't seem to find a suitable answer. I have a winsock2 application (code for server setup is adapted for my needs from [the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code)) and I simply want to display the server IPv4 address after binding.
This is the code I have so far (placed after binding to the ListenSocket):

```
    char ipv4[80];
    sockaddr_in inaddr;
    int len = sizeof(inaddr);
    int error = getsockname(m_ListenSocket, (sockaddr*)&inaddr, &len);
    const char* p = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &inaddr.sin_addr, ipv4, 80);
    std::cout << "Server address: " << ipv4 << std::endl;
```

However this will return "0.0.0.0". If I use `inet_ntop` with `struct addrinfo* result` (see linked documentation above) I get an IP starting with "2.xxx.xxx.xxx", while I know my local address is "192.168.1.18". In the code above, `error` is 0 and the result of inet_ntop is not `NULL`.
How does one get the actual IP address to show up?

Comment: If you've bound the socket to 0.0.0.0 then it doesn't have a single ip address

Comment: @AlanBirtles so this means, I have to use `gethostname()` and `gethostbyname()` to get the actual ip address? At least that what I assume after google searches...

Comment: That's certainly one way to do it but is rather circuitous, you can get the information directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902643/how-to-get-local-ip-address-of-windows-system

Comment: Oh man thanks a bunch, I'll have a look into it. My Google-Fu has really let me down today...

Comment: @RolandDeschain just note that approach will give you every IP on the system, not which IP(s) the socket is actually listening on. It is possible that it might not be able to listen on every possible IP, ie if some are in exclusive use, configured but disabled, etc. When binding to `0.0.0.0` the bind/listen will succeed as long as at least one IP interface is able to listen. But, there is no API to determine exactly which IP(s) the socket is actually listening on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hi yes this is of course true and should be noted. For my application it is ok, it is for a prototype app where I want it to work in different networks. Before, the IP was hardcoded, now I can choose in my client a IP address I want to connect to, which I can gather from the printed list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
// Link with Iphlpapi.lib
#pragma comment(lib,"IPHLPAPI.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Ws2_32.lib")

const unsigned int WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE = 15 * 1024;

void displayAddress(const SOCKET_ADDRESS &Address)
{
//  cout << "\n  Length of sockaddr: " << Address.iSockaddrLength;
    if (Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
    {
        sockaddr_in *si = (sockaddr_in *)(Address.lpSockaddr);
        char a[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(si->sin_addr), a, sizeof(a)))
            cout << "\n   IPv4 address: " << a;
    }
    else if (Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
    {
        sockaddr_in6 *si = (sockaddr_in6 *)(Address.lpSockaddr);
        char a[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {};
        if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(si->sin6_addr), a, sizeof(a)))
            cout << "\n   IPv6 address: " << a;
    }
}

int main(){
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    ULONG outBufLen = WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE;

    ULONG flags = GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = NULL;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = NULL;

    pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *) malloc(WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE);

    dwRetVal = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, flags, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen);

    if (dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        free(pAddresses);
        cout << "Buffer error!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    pCurrAddresses = pAddresses;
    while (pCurrAddresses) {

        for (PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pu = pCurrAddresses->FirstUnicastAddress; pu != NULL; pu = pu->Next)
            displayAddress(pu->Address);

        pCurrAddresses = pCurrAddresses->Next;
    }

    free(pAddresses);

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `GetAdaptersAddresses()` returns `ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`, you should simply reallocate `pAddresses` to the returned byte size and try again. Repeat this in a loop until `ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` is no longer returned, then react according to the final return value. It is unlikely that IP data will exceed 15K on most systems, but it could.